Change text of full_screen button ("Expand") in bslib card
How can one change the text (I need basically the translation to another language) of the expand button (which is created by full_screen = TRUE) and the close button in the full screen?


MWE:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel("Table in a card()"),
    
    mainPanel(
      card(
        title = "Data Table",
        full_screen = TRUE,
        tableOutput("mytable")
      )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Generate sample data
  data <- data.frame(
    Name = c("John", "Jane", "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50),
    Score = c(80, 75, 90, 85, 88, 92)
  )
  
  # Render table
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    filtered_data <- data
  })
}

# Run application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Below is a solution using JS, I currently don't see a possibility to do this directly using bslib built-in functions. However, note that if manipulating bslib functions is an option for you, then you could also try this, e.g. the 'Expand' is hard-coded in bslib:::full_screen_toggle().

library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Define UI
ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$script(
    HTML("$(document).ready(function(){
            // The 'Expand' text can be directly manipulated
            $('.card.bslib-card > bslib-tooltip > div').text('Erweitern');

            // The 'Close' text needs a mutation observer on the card because it
            // is only accessible if the full-screen mode is active.
            // We replace the html if the card has data-full-screen = true.
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                $('.bslib-full-screen-exit').html($('.bslib-full-screen-exit').html().replace('Close', 'Schließen'));
            });
            observer.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('card bslib-card')[0], { 
              attributes: true, 
              attributeFilter: ['data-full-screen'] });
          });")
    ),
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel("Table in a card()"),
  
  mainPanel(
    card(
      title = "Data Table",
      full_screen = TRUE,
      tableOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Generate sample data
  data <- data.frame(
    Name = c("John", "Jane", "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50),
    Score = c(80, 75, 90, 85, 88, 92)
  )
  
  # Render table
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    filtered_data <- data
  })
}

# Run application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Use this code in the header to ensure that the change applies to multiple cards across different nav_panels:
tags$script(
  HTML("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Change the text 'Expand' in all tooltips
      $('.card.bslib-card bslib-tooltip > div').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().includes('Expand')) {
          $(this).text('Expandir');
        }
      });

      // Use MutationObserver to change the text 'Close'
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        $('.bslib-full-screen-exit').each(function() {
          if ($(this).html().includes('Close')) {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Close', 'Cerrar'));
          }
        });
      });

      // Observe all elements with the class 'card bslib-card'
      $('.card.bslib-card').each(function() {
        observer.observe(this, { 
          attributes: true, 
          attributeFilter: ['data-full-screen'] 
        });
      });
    });
  ")
)

